# $\mathcal{A}\perp_\mathcal{G}\mathcal{B}\wedge\mathcal{H}\subseteq\mathcal{G}\implies\mathcal{A}\perp_\mathcal{H}\mathcal{B}$?

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-probability

If $\mathcal{A}\perp_\mathcal{G}\mathcal{B}$ and $\mathcal{H}\subseteq\mathcal{G}$, is it the case that $\mathcal{A}\perp_\mathcal{H}\mathcal{B}$? Here $\mathcal{A}$, $\mathcal{B}$, $\mathcal{G}$ and $\mathcal{H}$ are sub-$\sigma$-algebras of some common probability space $\left(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P\right)$ and $\cdot\perp_\square\cdot$ is the conditional independence relation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider a complete probability space for all the following underlying $\sigma$-fields. Then $\mathcal A\cap \mathcal B\subset\mathcal G$ (take $A$ in the intersection, then $P(A\mid\mathcal G)\in\{0,1\}$, and completeness ensures that $A\in\mathcal G$). To get a counter-example, take $\mathcal H:=\mathcal A\cap\mathcal B=\{\emptyset,X\}$ and $\mathcal A$ and $\mathcal B$ are not independent.

Comment: Thanks. Could you please elaborate just a little bit? Why does $\left(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P\right)$ need to be complete? What makes you think that $\mathcal{A}\cap\mathcal{B}\subseteq\mathcal{G}$?

Comment: I've added details.

Comment: Thanks. What do you mean by 'complete for a $\sigma$-field'? I know what a complete probability space is, but what does it mean for a probability space to be complete _for_ a sub-$\sigma$-field?

Comment: It means that the probability space made of the same set, the sub-sigma-algebra and the restriction of the measure to this sub-sigma-algebra, is complete.

Comment: If i understand correctly, this is the same as saying that, with $\mathcal{S}\in\left\{\mathcal{A},\mathcal{B},\mathcal{G},\mathcal{H}\right\}$, whenever $P(S)=0$ for some $S\in\mathcal{S}$, $S'\in\mathcal{S}$ for all $S'\subseteq S$.

Comment: But if this is the case, i don't understand your claim: "then $\mathcal A\cap \mathcal B\subset\mathcal G$ (take $A$ in the intersection, then $P(A\mid\mathcal G)\in\{0,1\}$, and completeness ensures that $A\in\mathcal G$)". I see why $A\in\mathcal{A}\cap\mathcal{B}$ implies $P\left(A\mid\mathcal{G}\right)\in\left\{0,1\right\}$, which in turn implies, by the law of total probability, that $P(A)\in\left\{0,1\right\}$. But why does this mean that $A\in\mathcal{G}$?

Comment: Completeness means that each event (contained in a set of) null measure is measurable. If $P(A)=0$ then $A$ is measurable, and if $P(A)=1$ do the same with $A^c$.

Comment: So by writing "Consider a complete probability space for all the following underlying σ-fields", you meant to say that (supposing the probability space is $\left(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P\right)$), whenever $A\subseteq B\in\mathcal{F}$ with $P(B)=0$, $A\in\mathcal{A}\cap\mathcal{B}\cap\mathcal{G}\cap\mathcal{H}$?

Comment: Yes.${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: Got it. Thanks!

Comment: Davide, i apologize, but in hindsight something doesn't make sense to me. Since for all $E\in\mathcal{A}\cap\mathcal{B}$, $P(E)\in\left\{0,1\right\}$, and whenever $E\in\mathcal{F}$ with $P(E)=0$, $E\in\mathcal{A}\cap\mathcal{B}\cap\mathcal{G}\cap\mathcal{H}$, it must be that $\mathcal{A}\cap\mathcal{B}\subseteq\mathcal{H}$!

Comment: You are right. Please unaccept the answer. Then I will delete it and think more deeply about the problem.

Comment: Actually, my answer was misleading: the probability space cannot be complete with respect to $\mathcal H$. Taking $\mathcal H:=\mathcal A\cap\mathcal B=\{0,X\}$, where $\mathcal A$ and $\mathcal B$ are independent it seems we get a counter-example.

Comment: Now it's great. Thank!

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to describe a slight variation on Davide's answer that i find crisper.

Suppose $\mathcal{A}$ and $\mathcal{B}$ are dependent fields that are conditionally independent given $\mathcal{G}$ (see, e.g., [the Wikipedia article on Conditional Independence](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Conditional_independence&oldid=554115966)) and let $\mathcal{H}:=\left\{\emptyset,\Omega\right\}$. Then independence conditional on $\mathcal{H}$ is the same as unconditional independence, hence the desired result.